# Replace One Centre-Tapped Resistor with Two Resistors

Tags: resistors, vacuum-tube, vintage, guitar-amplifier, centre-tapped

I have just started research and design on a small tube guitar amp and have hit the first of what is probably many uncertainties. The idea is to reuse the transformers, 7C5 power tube and 7Y4 rectification tube from an old 1950s [Philco 1224 Gramophone Radio](https://www.vintageradio.co.nz/model/philco/1224). For additional context, I'd also like to use a couple of 7F7 tubes in the preamp section, but you obviously won't see those in the schematic.

The full schematic of the original gramophone is available at the link above, but my specific question relates to (what I *think* is) a 1500 ohm, 10 watt resistor in the power filter section:

[image: schematic snippet]

If my understanding is correct, then the resistor is centre tapped, from which one of the two B+ lines is taken.

I'm struggling to find a resistor (within budget) which matches this description, so my plan is to replace it with two 750 ohm resistors in series, and this same B+ line could then be taken from the intersection between them.

What I'm not sure of, if this is indeed possible, is what the power rating of these two resistors ought to be. My *very* sketchy understanding of Ohm's law makes me think that I need to increase their rating, but my gut wants me to cut them both to 5W.

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer this properly, we would need to know the DC current drawn from each of the 270V and 250V lines. In the absence of that information we can make educated guesses.

If we assume that after the capacitors have all charged up to their operating voltages, average current in those capacitors from then on will be zero, and we can treat all resistor currents as an average over time, DC, ignoring the capacitors. From the power rating of the 100Ω resistor, which is 1W:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P &= I^2R \\ \\
I &= \sqrt{\frac{P}{R}} \\ \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{1W}{100\Omega}} \\ \\
&= 100mA \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

That's an absolute maximum, and I would expect the designer to choose a 1W device if current were considerably less than this, which I'll address below.

If that current were to pass through 750Ω this would dissipate

$$P=I^2R = 0.1^2\times 750 = 7.5W$$

justifying the 10W second/third resistors. This is not really in agreement with the DC voltages shown, which imply certain voltages across the resistors, from which we can derive expected power in each resistor. For the left 750Ω:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P &= \frac{V^2}{R} \\ \\
&= \frac{{(310V - 270V)}^2}{750\Omega} \\ \\
&= 2.1W
\end{aligned}
$$

The right-hand 750Ω:

$$
\begin{aligned}
&= \frac{{(270V - 250V)}^2}{750\Omega} \\ \\
&= 0.53W
\end{aligned}
$$

That's a total of 2.6W, well below the 10W rating of the centre-tapped 1.5kΩ unit, so I suspect those marked DC voltages are no-load test values, with motor off and no input signal, for instance.

The voltages across those two half-resistors, under full load, will no doubt be significantly greater than the shown values, and I'd rather trust the 100mA maximum current estimate. Guessing that the designer would want a 75% safety margin on power, current through the 1W, 100Ω resistor would be:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P &= I^2R \\ \\
0.75 \times 1W &= I^2 \times 100\Omega \\ \\
I &=  \sqrt{\frac{0.75 \times 1W}{100\Omega}} \\ \\
&= 87mA
\end{aligned}
$$

This current will *all* pass through the first of the 750Ω resistors, but only a fraction of that will pass through the second one, a fact which is clear from Kirchhoff's current law:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7Mzb8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

For R2, its power dissipation while passing 87mA is:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P &= I^2R \\ \\
&= (87mA)^2 \times 750 \\ \\
&= 5.7W \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Again assuming a 75% power margin, this leaves \$(0.75\times 10W) - 5.7W = 1.8W\$ for the right half of the 1.5kΩ. Just to know, this corresponds to a current drawn from the 250V rail of:

$$
\begin{aligned}
P &= I^2R \\ \\
1.8W &= I^2 \times 750\Omega \\ \\
I &= \sqrt{\frac{1.8W}{750\Omega}} \\ \\
&= 49mA
\end{aligned}
$$

By making a lot of assumptions, I am estimating:

$$ P_{R2} = 6W $$
$$ P_{R3} = 2W $$

I would advise to use a 10W device for R2, and *at least* 3W for R3.
Of course, all this will be made easier if you used those values provisionally, and actually measure the current through R3. That way you could know for sure.

Comment: This is amazing, thank you for showing your process and working math!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can replace them with two 750Ω resistors.

I would suggest replacing them both with 10W resistors, the left one gets more continuous power dissipation and more surge (mostly under oddball conditions for the latter), so at least the left one should be 10W.

Eg. Yageo [SQP10AJB-750R](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/447/YAGEO_SQP_NSP_datasheet_2021v0-3003003.pdf), less than $1 each.